# Extending IQueryable with IsInDateTimeRange

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, iqueryable, linq-expressions

So I am getting somewhat tired of rewriting the same queries over and over again.

```
repo.Query().Where(stuff => stuff.Timestamp >= minTime && stuff.Timestamp <= maxTime && ...);
```

I thought I should extend `IQueryable` with a method called `IsInDateTimeRange`, and use it like this

```
repo.Query().IsInDateTimeRange(stuff => stuff.Timestamp, minTime, maxTime) ...
```

this would be very easy for `IEnumerable`, just a `Func<T, DateTime>` and two `DateTime`s, however for the `IQueryable` I needs to take an `Expression` and I am not really sure how to use this.

This was my attempt, but does not seem to be working.

```
public static IQueryable<TValue> IsInDateTimeRange<TValue>(
        this IQueryable<TValue> self,
        Expression<Func<TValue, DateTime>> getMember,
        DateTime minTime,
        DateTime maxTime)
    {
        return self.Where(value => minTime >= getMember(value) && maxTime <= getMember(value));
    }
```

Comment: When you say not working please explain what it means. Exception? Compile error?..

Comment: Most Linq providers wouldn't be able to translate your transformed expression into a store query because of that `getMember(value)` noise. You'll have to manually replace the relevant parts with a regular `Expression.Property` accessor.

Comment: Yes, compiler error. can't call getMember since it's not a delegate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this by manually building the expression based on the property access expression that is passed to the method:

```
public static IQueryable<TValue> IsInDateTimeRange<TValue>(
    this IQueryable<TValue> self,
    Expression<Func<TValue, DateTime>> getMember,
    DateTime minTime,
    DateTime maxTime)
{
    var getMemberBody = getMember.Body;
    var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<TValue, bool>>(
        Expression.And(
            Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
                Expression.Constant(minTime),
                getMemberBody
            ),
            Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
                getMemberBody,
                Expression.Constant(maxTime)
            )
        ),
        getMember.Parameters
    );
    return self.Where(filter);
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  Only tweak I might make is that you don't actually need to take `getMember.Parameters.First()`.  You should be able to just pass `getMembers.Parameters` as the second argument to `Lambda<>()`.  Also, the first `LessThanOrEqual` should be `GreaterThanOrEqual` :).

Comment: Fixed the minor logic error for you (you used  `<=` twice).

Comment: Um that was intened ..min <= value && value <= max

Comment: *(facepalm)* I have not had my coffee yet.  Reverted!

Comment: It's ok, I thought about the operators for a bit too :)

Comment: @jool If this answer solved your problem, kindly reward Titan by marking it as accepted.  That will give him the reputation points he has earned :).